# Overwriting data in memory

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, ocaml

I've written a password manager in Ocaml. In order to make it as secure as possible, I'd like to store a string (an encryption key) in memory in such a way that it can be overwritten. <strike>Since Ocaml is pass by value</strike> , and there's a garbage collector, this has proven difficult. I encrypt all buffers and variables I can, but I still need a "session key" stored to do this. To prevent this from being detected by automated key searching programs or put into swap, it's assembled from a bunch of random data in a buffer using a random increment. So really, all I need is a single variable that can be overwritten for the assembled key for a few seconds before it's passed into the Nocrypto library... Would a reference work for this?

According to this [cornell "Refs and Arrays" page](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2013sp/supplemental/recitations/rec10.html), refs are mutable and work similarly to pointers in C. That being said, I also found a stack overflow answer discussing [Ocaml refs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004245/does-ocaml-have-the-ability-to-pass-by-reference), in which the answer mentions "they act like pointers to new allocated memory". Does this mean every time, it just allocates a new thing in memory instead of actually mutating the stuff in memory? If so, you couldn't really "overwrite" a ref.

Other possible solutions I've come across are Bigarrays, and "custom blocks". I'm not entirely sure if "custom blocks" are actually allocated outside of the scope of garbage collection or not. They seem like they're used to access external C code. Are they copied around by the garbage collector? Could they be "overwritten?" There's also this idea of "opaque bytes" and opaque objects in memory. I'm having a pretty hard time wrapping my head around how this all fits together. A useful but confusing (to me) discussion of custom blocks in memory on stack overflow is here: [Are custom blocks ever copied in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363597/are-custom-blocks-ever-copied-by-ocaml) Answer says they can be moved around. Even so, could they be overwritten?

The last possible solution is to store it using a Cstruct like the Nocrypto library seems to do. They discuss it in this github issue: [Secret material erasure](https://github.com/mirleft/ocaml-nocrypto/issues/11) The asker states:

> "Granted, most key material is Cstruct.t, which is a Bigarray.Array1.t, which is allocated outside of the GC heap"

Is this even correct? If so, I can't seem to find a source file that actually does this. I'm pretty new to Ocaml and functional programming in general. If you're curious, my program is located on github here: [ocaml-pass](https://github.com/Jchase2/ocaml-pass)

Comment: As a side note, OCaml is pass-by-reference, not pass-by-value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## TL;DR;

You shall not store any secret information in OCaml heap. Thus you must never copy your secret into any OCaml heap-allocated value, consequently, neither Bytes, nor Strings or Arrays could be used, even temporary.

## Introduction to the OCaml Memory Model

OCaml values are uniformly represented as tagged machine words. The least significant bit of a word is used as a tag, that distinguishes between pointers (tag=0) and immediate values (tag=1). Thus a value has always a fixed size, and is a pointer or an immediate.

Immediate values store their data in the most significant part of the word, that is 31-bits in 32 bit systems, and 63 bits in 64-bit systems. Pointers store their data in blocks, that are located in a so-called *OCaml Heap*. The OCaml Heap is a set of blocks managed by the Garbage Collector (GC). A block is a chunk of data prefixed with a header. The header specifies the size of data, and some other meta information, used by the GC. Block can contain OCaml values (pointers or immediate values) or opaque data.

To summarize. All OCaml values are represented as machine words, that either store data directly in the word or are pointers to heap-allocated blocks. Each pointer points to one and only one block. Several pointers may point to the same block. Such values are considered physically equal. Some blocks are not pointed by any pointers. Such blocks are called dead and are reclaimed by the GC.

## Introduction to the OCaml Garbage Collector

The GC manages blocks, by allocating, moving, and deallocating them. The GC itself uses an arena, that is either obtained from the C memory allocator (malloc) or directly from a kernel via the memmap syscall (depends on a particular system and runtime).

The GC is generational, that means that values are first allocated in a special region of a heap called *minor heap*. The minor heap is a contiguous region of memory of fixed size, represented in the runtime with three pointers: the pointer `beg` to the beginning of the minor heap, a pointer `end` to the end of the minor heap, and the pointer `cur` to the beginning of the free area of the minor heap. When a block is allocated, `cur` is increased by the size of the block. Then the block is initialized with data. When there is no more free space in the minor heap (i.e., then `end - cur` is less than the required block size), then a minor GC cycle is triggered. The GC analyzes all blocks stored in the Minor Heap and copies all blocks that are referenced by at least one pointer to the *Major Heap*. After that, the `cur` pointer is set to `beg`.

In the Major Heap, a block may also be copied several times during a process called *compaction*. The compactor may try to rearrange blocks in its arena in order to achieve more compact representation of the heap.

## Security Consequences

As the OCaml GC is a moving GC, it may copy the heap-allocated data arbitrarily. Although it is called *moving*, it is still in fact just copying. I.e., when a block is moved from the minor heap to the major heap, it is in fact just bit-copied, and thus is duplicated. The block phantom in the minor heap may live for an arbitrary amount of time until it is overwritten by some newly allocated value. When an object is moved during the compaction, it is also copied, and may or may not be overwritten during the process. And, of course, it goes without saying, that once a block becomes dead, it still may survive in a heap for an arbitrary amount of time until reused by the GC.

That all means, that if a secret ends up in the OCaml heap, it will go wild, as the GC can replicate it multiple times in an arbitrary and rather unpredictable ways. Thus, we can only store secrets either in immediate values or in regions that are not controlled by the GC. As it was said before, all OCaml values that are pointers, always point to a block in the OCaml heap. A block may contain data directly, or it could contain a pointer itself, that will point outside the memory heap. The so-called custom blocks, may or may not store their information in the OCaml heap, it depeds on a particular representation of each custom block. For example, the Bigarray library provides custom blocks that store their payload outside of the OCaml heap. Thus a Bigarray is a custom block, that has two fields: a pointer and size. It is an opaque block, i.e., the GC will never treat these two values as OCaml values, and will never follow neither the size nor the pointer. The data pointed by a pointer is located outside of the OCaml heap, and is either allocated by `malloc` or by `memmap` (in fact, it could be arbitrary integer, and even point to stack, or static data, it doesn't really matter, as long as we treat bigarrays just as a `ptr,len` pair).

This all makes Bigarrays ideal for storing secrets. We can be sure, that they are not moved by the GC, we can overwrite them to prevent the information leakage once they are freed.

## Further considerations

We should be careful, and never allow a secret to be copied into the OCaml heap from our safe place. That means, that even if our main storage is a safe bigarray the information will still leak if we will copy its contents to an OCaml string. Consequently, if we first read the information into OCaml string, and then copy it into bigarray, the information will still leak. Thus, any interface that uses OCaml heap-allocated values is unsafe and shall not be used. For example, we can't use OCaml channels to read or write secrets (we should rely on memory mapping or unbuffered IO provided by the Unix module). And again, whenever you get a `string` data type from a Bigarray, you get your data copied, with all the ramifications.

Comment: Thanks for such a write-up, this is super interesting! Just a question to follow up with your conclusion. Could you give pointers as to how to manipulate data without it ever showing up in the OCaml heap? Relying entirely on C code and just using OCaml to fire the whole thing up?

Comment: That basically means that the type should be purely abstract, and provide operation such as equal, iter, map, compare, and the IO operations.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the easiest way to do this is with [ocaml-cstructs](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cstruct), which uses Bigarray. I'll have to rewrite a bunch of functions, but since a lot of the data can remain encrypted until operated on, it shouldn't be too bad. Bit tricky.

Comment: Looks like, in the [source code](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/pervasives.ml) of pervasives.ml, the output functions operate using their own bindings. Even if everything is in Bigarrays, as soon as anything needs printed, it'll end up leaking anyway. I think. Not to mention the regex library I'm using. Seems like Ocaml might be a bad choice for this if I want to keep everything out of memory. Maybe something along the lines of [encrypting a processes memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052942/linux-of-equivalent-cryptprotectmemory) would be best.

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying, you can implement printing using the `Unix` interface, you should never use channels or any other buffered IO. Concerning the regex... do you really need to apply regexes on secrets?

Comment: Right, I see where you mentioned that now. Still getting used to a lot of this lower level terminology. Regex isn't necessary, just a lot more convenient. This is a more difficult problem than I anticipated. Learning a lot though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a value of type `bytes`, essentially a mutable array of bytes:

```
# let buffer = Bytes.make 16 'x';;
val buffer : bytes = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
# Bytes.set buffer 0 'T';;
- : unit = ()
# buffer;;
- : bytes = "Txxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
# Bytes.fill buffer 0 16 ' ';;
- : unit = ()
# buffer;;
- : bytes = "                "
```

You can overwrite with `Bytes.fill` after you're done.